# postgreSQL returning Id's of updated rows using entity framework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am trying to return the ID's of the rows that were affected by an update. I am using entity frameworks ExecuteSqlCommand and postgreSQL database. When I execute the command all I get as a return value is -1. What am I doing wrong?

```
var updatedIds = _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"UPDATE dbo.""PrincipleCategoryObjectives"" SET ""IsRequired""=" + requiredDto.IsRequired + @" WHERE ""AuditPrincipleId""=" + requiredDto.PrincipleId + @" RETURNING ""Id""");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExecuteSqlCommand returns the number of rows affected, and not any value returned by the query itself ([see the API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_ExecuteSqlCommand_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_System_FormattableString_)).

To get a value returned from your SQL, you can drop down to ADO.NET. Call `_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()` to get a plain old DbConnection, create a DbCommand on that connection with your SQL and call `ExecuteScalar()` on that (see the many tutorials on the web if you need help).

Comment: yea i ended up going the ADO route and returned the values in a datareader so i could loop through them and grab what i needed.